# Estimating the Model from Part of the Data

Tags: r, modeling

I am trying to model a system using a simple quadratic function.

I have theoretic reasons why this is the appropriate model of the physiological process.

Assume the model is: X --> F(X) --> Y

I assume that Y = C + B*X + A*X*X

Lets suppose I have two sets of data collected from this system which have different ranges of X.

One has X values from 10 to 90 and the other has X values from 30 to 80.

I would like to estimate A, B and C so that they model the underlying system and the estimates are not specific to one data set or the other.

How can I do this?

I am testing by using a full dataset and fitting the quadratic, then using a subset of data and fitting the quadratic again and getting different parameter estimates of A, B and C.

Is there some method (some orthogonalization/projection of X) where A, B and C are the same regardless of whether I use dataset one or two?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want parameter values that work for any value of $X$, you should fit the model to the whole dataset, as you mentioned first. That you get different estimates on a subset shouldn't be a surprise, and may be a manifestation of [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox), but isn't a reason to believe those estimates in preference to the estimates from the whole sample.